# Firebase. Добавление своих данных

Tags: javascript, база-данных, firebase, firebase-database

Здравствуйте, ребята. У меня такой вопрос.
Короче, я сделал авторизацию пользователей через Email & Phone. Короче все это работает. Вопрос в том, как мне добавить этому пользователю свои данные. Например: Я хочу при авторизации пользователя обновлять его местоположение через GeoIP или просто добавить ему время входа.

Если не совсем понятно, то есть методы user'а (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User). Мне как бы нужен метод `updateProfile`.
Реализация `updateProfile` из документации:

```
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  var displayName = user.displayName;
  var photoURL = user.photoURL;
}, function(error) {
});
```

Но этом метод работает только с ключами, которые уже есть в пользователя. Я имею ввиду, что свои добавить нельзя.

Как мне добавить свои данные пользователю? Database не очень подходит!
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в Realtime Database вашего проекта дополнительный список для хранения кастомной информации для пользователей.

В rules это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
{
  "rules": {
...
    "userinfo": {
      "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
...
  }
}
```

Таким образом ожно будет получать данные

GET https://{{project_name}}.firebaseio.com/userinfo/{{user_id}}.json?auth={{server_key}}

И дабавлять свои

POST https://{{project_name}}.firebaseio.com/userinfo/{{user_id}}.json?auth={{server_key}}

```
{
  "name": "Kirk",
  "gender": "MALE",
  "avatar": null,
  "birthDate": 1502463043
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это хороший метод